# Choropleth Plotly Indonesia

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I'm trying to make Choropleth Indonesia using Plotly, but I still confused about `locationmode` and `geo_scope` of Indonesia. How to figure it out?

```
fig8 = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations=df['Column'], # Spatial coordinates
    z = df['Columnnext'], # Data to be color-coded
    locationmode = 'ISO-3', # set of locations match entries in `locations`
    colorscale = 'Reds',
    colorbar_title = "Column",
))

fig8.update_layout(
    title_text = 'Title Bla Bla Bla',
    geo_scope='asia',
)

fig8.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**plotly** is packaged with country and US state geometry.  If you want to have a choropleth of Indonesia showing different regions / provinces you need to supply the *geojson*

In this example I have pretty much used you code as as, using this https://github.com/superpikar/indonesia-geojson geometry.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# indonesia geojson
geojson = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/superpikar/indonesia-geojson/master/indonesia-province-simple.json"
).json()

# dataframe with columns referenced in question
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Column": pd.json_normalize(geojson["features"])["properties.Propinsi"]}
).assign(Columnnext=lambda d: d["Column"].str.len())

fig8 = go.Figure(
    data=go.Choropleth(
        geojson=geojson,
        locations=df["Column"],  # Spatial coordinates
        featureidkey="properties.Propinsi",
        z=df["Columnnext"],  # Data to be color-coded
        colorscale="Reds",
        colorbar_title="Column",
    )
)
fig8.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)

fig8
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without `geo_scope`

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations=df['code'], # Spatial coordinates
    z = df['total exports'].astype(float), # Data to be color-coded
    locationmode = 'USA-states', # set of locations match entries in `locations`
    colorscale = 'Reds',
    colorbar_title = "Millions USD",
))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text = '2011 US Agriculture Exports by State',
    # geo_scope='usa', # limite map scope to USA
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

With `geo_scope`

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations=df['code'], # Spatial coordinates
    z = df['total exports'].astype(float), # Data to be color-coded
    locationmode = 'USA-states', # set of locations match entries in `locations`
    colorscale = 'Reds',
    colorbar_title = "Millions USD",
))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text = '2011 US Agriculture Exports by State',
    geo_scope='usa', # limite map scope to USA
)

fig.show("browser")
```

[image]